# Delphi: How to show a compound component?

Tags: delphi

I have a check box control with a labeled edit as a published subcomponent.

What I'm trying to do is create a Translate procedure for the check box that would show the labeled edit on top, and allow the user to change the text of the check box's caption. Something like this:

```
constructor TPBxCheckBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FTranslateEdit := TLabeledEdit.Create(Self);
  FTranslateEdit.Parent := Self.Parent;
  FTranslateEdit.SetSubComponent(True);
  FTranslateEdit.Visible := False;
end;    

procedure TPBxCheckBox.Translate(Show: Boolean);
begin
  TranslateEdit.Left := Self.Left;
  TranslateEdit.Top := Self.Top;
  TranslateEdit.EditLabel.Caption := Self.Caption;
  TranslateEdit.Text := Self.Caption;
  TranslateEdit.Visible := Show;
  TranslateEdit.Width := Self.Width;
end;
```

But this doesn't work - the labeled edit is never shown.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859524/how-to-initialize-a-custom-control/64974040?noredirect=1#comment114931111_64974040

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't show because at `TPBxCheckBox.Create()` time `Parent` isn't yet assigned, so you're basically doing `TranslateEdit.Parent := nil;`.

If you really want your TranslatedEdit to have the same parent as the TPBxCheckBox itself, you could override `SetParet` and take action at the moment TPBxCheckBox's Parent is Assigned. Something like this:

```
TPBxCheckBox = class(TWhatever)
protected
  procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
end;

procedure TPBxCheckBox.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited;
  TranslatedEdit.Parent := AParent;
end;
```

Comment: Why the negative vote?! This the correct answer to the question.

Comment: The Delphi tag is haunted by an anonymous downvoter that apparently randomly downvotes stuff.

Comment: it seems that in the Delphi area is an 'delphi-hater' which down vote by 'random',without reason. I don't understand why there isn't a rule like 'you can not down vote without reason'.Something that obliges you to write a comment before down voting. +1 for seeing the problem and provide the correct answer Cosmin

Comment: I was always pro "specify reason in order to downvote"

Answer (score 0):

When I make components with multiple parts I have not used the SetSubComponent method.

What I have done is something like this

```
constructor TPBxCheckBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FTranslateEdit := TLabeledEdit.Create(Self);
  FTranslateEdit.Parent := Self;
  FTranslateEdit.Visible := False;
end;
```

And I would try something like this

```
procedure TPBxCheckBox.Translate(Show: Boolean);
begin
  FTranslateEdit.EditLabel.Caption := Self.Caption;
  FTranslateEdit.Left := Self.Left;
  FTranslateEdit.Top := Self.Top;
  FTranslateEdit.Width := Self.Width;
  FTranslateEdit.Height := Self.Height;
  FTranslateEdit.Text := Self.Caption;
  FTranslateEdit.Visible := Show;
end;
```

I'll improve this answer if you get me more information or if I get time to test this out.

Comment: Ignoring the translate procedure, and in the constructor you set visible to true does it still not show up?

Comment: The lines that set up Left, Top, Width and Height are useless: they're initialized after the constructor finishes, so at the time the constructor run they have the default value of 0. An other issue is with `TPBxCheckBox`: since it's probably an actual check box, it doesn't have the WS_CLIPCHILDREN window style so the checkbox might simply draw over TranslateEdit, making it invisible.