# How to initialize a custom control?

Tags: delphi

I want to create my own custom control. Let's say I want to initialize its graphic properties. Obviously I cannot do that in Create because a canvas/handle is not YET allocated.

The same if my custom control contains a subcomponent (and I also set its visual properties).

There are quite several places on SO that discuss the creation of a custom control. They don't really agree on it.

**AfterConstruction** is out of question because the handle is not ready yet.

**CreateWnd** seem ok but it actually can be quite problematic as it can be called more than once (for example when you apply a new skin to the program). Probably, some boolean variable should be used to check if CreateWnd was called more than once.

**SetParent** has the same issue: if you change the parent of your custom control, whatever code you put in its SetParent will be executed again. A bool variable should fix the problem.

Comment: Typically, creating a sub-control and setting its `Parent` property to your main control will work just fine inside of your main control's constructor, provided that the sub-control does not require a valid `HWND` right way, which is not common. If it does require an `HWND`, you can have your main control override the virtual `SetParent()` method to update the sub-control when its own `Parent` is set after construction. Or `CreateWnd()`/`CreateWindowHandle()` will work, since that is when your main control creates its own `HWND` when its `Handle` property is accessed without an `HWND` assigned

Comment: On a side note, `CreateWnd()` is called before `CreateWindowHandle()`, as it is the base class `TWinControl.CreateWnd()` that calls `CreateWindowHandle()`.  You are calling `inherited` before logging your messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-How do you set the properties (including Parent) when the component is created dynamically? Only Create and AfterConstruction are called then.

Comment: Simply create the child control in the parent's constructor and set its properties at the time it is created. And set the parent's properties in the parent's constructor, too. If you are encountering a problem with doing that, then the parent/child is likely doing something it should not be doing. You need to show your real code and explain what the ACTUAL problem is

Comment: *".. when the component is created dynamically? Only Create and AfterConstruction are called .."* Setting the parent is what causes CreateWnd to be called - because then the control needs a handle. IOW your testing is incomplete, log the order of events once you set the parent in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Principles

First al all, most of the visual properties of a control do *not* require the control to have a valid window handle in order to be set. It is a false assumption that they do.

Once the object that constitutes a control is created, i.e. the constructor has been executed, normally all (visual) properties like size, position, font, color, alignment, etc. can be set. Or they should be able to, preferably. For sub controls, also the `Parent` ideally must be set as soon as the constructor has run. For the component itself, that constructor would be the inherited constructor during its own constructor.

The reason this works is that all these kind of properties are stored within the fields of the Delphi object itself: they are *not* immediately passed to the Windows API. That happens in `CreateWnd` but no sooner than when all necessary parent window handles are resolved and assigned.

So the short answer is: the initial setup of a custom component is done in its constructor, because it is the only routine that runs once.

But the question (unintentionally) touches a wide range of topics on component building, because the complexity of an initial setup of a control depends entirely on the type of control and the properties that are to be set.

### Example

Consider writing this (useless yet illustrative) component that consists of a panel with a combo box aligned on top of it. The panel should initially have: no caption, a custom height and a silver background. The combo box should have: a custom font size and a 'picklist' style.

```
type
  TMyPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    FComboBox: TComboBox;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

constructor TMyPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Color := clSilver;
  ShowCaption := False;
  Height := 100;
  FComboBox := TComboBox.Create(Self);
  FComboBox.Parent := Self;
  FComboBox.Align := alTop;
  FComboBox.Style := csDropDownList;
  FComboBox.Font.Size := 12;
end;
```

### Framework conformity

A component writer could now consider it done, **but it is not**. He/she has the responsibility to write components properly as described by the comprehensive Delphi [Component Writer's Guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Component_Writer%27s_Guide_Index).

Note that no less then four properties (indicated bold in the object inspector) are needlessly stored in the DFM because of an incorrect designtime component definition. Although invisible, the caption property still reads *MyPanel1*, which is against te requirements. This can be solved by removing the applicable [control style](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Controls.TControlStyle). The `ShowCaption`, `Color` and `ParentBackground` properties lack a proper [default property value](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Default_Property_Values).

Note too that all default properties of `TPanel` are present, but you might want some not te be, especially the `ShowCaption` property. This can be prevented by descending from the right class type. The standard controls in the Delphi framework mostly offer a custom variant, e.g. `TCustomEdit` instead of `TEdit` that are there for exactly this reason.

Our example compound control that is rid of these issues looks as follows:

```
type
  TMyPanel = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FComboBox: TComboBox;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property Color default clSilver;
    property ParentBackground default False;
  end;

constructor TMyPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Color := clSilver;
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csSetCaption];
  Height := 100;
  FComboBox := TComboBox.Create(Self);
  FComboBox.Parent := Self;
  FComboBox.Align := alTop;
  FComboBox.Style := csDropDownList;
  FComboBox.Font.Size := 12;
end;
```

Of course, other implications due to setting up a component are possible.

### Exceptions

Unfortunately there áre properties that require a control's valid window handle, because the control stores its value in Windows' native control. Take the `Items` property of the combo box above for example. Consider a deisgn time requirement of it been filled with some predefined text items. You then should need to **override `CreateWnd`** and add the text items the first time that it is called.

Sometimes the initial setup of a control depends on other controls. At design time you don't (want to) have control over the order in which all controls are read. In such case, you need to **override `Loaded`**. Consider a design time requirement of adding all menu-items from the `PopupMenu` property, if any, to the `Items` property of the combo box.

The example above, extended with these new features, results finally in:

```
type
  TMyPanel = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FInitialized: Boolean;
    FComboBox: TComboBox;
    procedure Initialize;
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure Loaded; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property Color default clSilver;
    property ParentBackground default False;
    property PopupMenu;
  end;

constructor TMyPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Color := clSilver;
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csSetCaption];
  Height := 100;
  FComboBox := TComboBox.Create(Self);
  FComboBox.Parent := Self;
  FComboBox.Align := alTop;
  FComboBox.Style := csDropDownList;
  FComboBox.Font.Size := 12;
end;

procedure TMyPanel.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited CreateWnd;
  if not FInitialized then
    Initialize;
end;

procedure TMyPanel.Initialize;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if HandleAllocated then
  begin
    if Assigned(PopupMenu) then
      for I := 0 to PopupMenu.Items.Count - 1 do
        FComboBox.Items.Add(PopupMenu.Items[I].Caption)
    else
      FComboBox.Items.Add('Test');
    FInitialized := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyPanel.Loaded;
begin
  inherited Loaded;
  Initialize;
end;
```

It is also possible that the component depends in some way on its parent. Then **override `SetParent`**, but also remember that any dependency on (properties of) its parent likely indicates a design issue which might require re-evaluation.

And surely there are other kind of dependencies imaginable. They then would require special handling somewhere else in the component code. Or another question here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

So, I did this test that shows the creation order.

```
UNIT cvTester;

{--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 This file tests the initialization order of a custom control.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

INTERFACE
{$WARN GARBAGE OFF}    { Silent the: 'W1011 Text after final END' warning }

USES
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, vcl.Controls, vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;


TYPE
  TCustomCtrlTest = class(TPanel)
    private
    protected
      Initialized: boolean;
      Sub: TButton;
    public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
      procedure Loaded; override;
      procedure AfterConstruction; override;
      procedure CreateWnd; override;
      procedure CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams); override;
      procedure WriteToString(s: string);
      procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
    published
  end;



procedure Register;

IMPLEMENTATION
USES System.IOUtils;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Mine', [TCustomCtrlTest]);
end;



constructor TCustomCtrlTest.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Sub:= TButton.Create(Self);
  Sub.Parent:= Self;            // Typically, creating a sub-control and setting its Parent property to your main control will work just fine inside of your main control's constructor, provided that the sub-control does not require a valid HWND right way. Remy Lebeau

  WriteToString('Create'+ #13#10);
end;


procedure TCustomCtrlTest.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  WriteToString('Loaded'+ #13#10);
end;


procedure TCustomCtrlTest.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  WriteToString('AfterConstruction'+ #13#10);
end;


procedure TCustomCtrlTest.CreateWnd;
begin
  WriteToString(' CreateWnd'+ #13#10);
  inherited;
  WriteToString(' CreateWnd post'+ #13#10);

  Sub.Visible:= TRUE;
  Sub.Align:= alLeft;
  Sub.Caption:= 'SOMETHING';
  Sub.Font.Size:= 20;
end;


procedure TCustomCtrlTest.CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateWindowHandle(Params);
  WriteToString('  CreateWindowHandle'+ #13#10);
end;


procedure TCustomCtrlTest.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  WriteToString('SetParent'+ #13#10);
  inherited SetParent(AParent);
  WriteToString('SetParent post'+ #13#10);
  if NOT Initialized then { Make sure we don't call this code twice }
   begin
    Initialized:= TRUE;
    SetMoreStuffHere;
   end;
end;




procedure TCustomCtrlTest.WriteToString(s: string);
begin
 System.IOUtils.TFile.AppendAllText('test.txt', s);
 // The output will be in Delphi\bin folder when the control is used inside the IDE (dropped on a form) c:\Delphi\Delphi XE7\bin\
 // and in app's folder when running inside the EXE file.
end;
end.
```

The order is:

```
 Dropping control on a form:
    Create
    AfterConstruction
    SetParent
     CreateWnd
      CreateWindowHandle
     CreateWnd post
    SetParent post

  Deleting control from form:
    SetParent
    SetParent post

  Cutting ctrol from form and pasting it back:
    SetParent
    SetParent post
    Create
    AfterConstruction
    SetParent
     CreateWnd
      CreateWindowHandle
     CreateWnd post
    SetParent post
    SetParent
    SetParent post
    Loaded

 Executing the program
    Create
    AfterConstruction
    SetParent
    SetParent post
    SetParent
    SetParent post
    Loaded
     CreateWnd
      CreateWindowHandle
     CreateWnd post

 Dynamic creation
   Create
   AfterConstruction
   SetParent
    CreateWnd
     CreateWindowHandle
    CreateWnd post
   SetParent post

 Reconstructing the form
    Not tested yet
```

---

The solution I chose in the end is to initialize code that requires a handle in SetParent (or CreateWnd) and use a boolean var to protect from executing that code twice (see SetParent above).